# How to insert an image into SQL Server Database using jsp

Tags: sql-server, image, jsp

I need to insert an imagen into a SQL Server Database and i need to do it using jsp, but i don't know how to do it. Someone can teach me the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend use `jsp` alone to achieve this task as it is meant to use as a view technology.

For any file upload functionality, use `@MultiPartConfig` from servlet 3.0 specification.

in your jsp file:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/your-servlet-path">
    <input type="file" name="myimage" />
</form>
```

in your servlet:

```
@MultiPartConfig
@WebServlet("/your-servlet-path")
public class FileUploadServlet extends HttpServlet{

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception{
        Part imagePart = req.getPart("myimage");
        InputStream partInputStream = imagePart.getInputStream();
        //read byte array from input stream


         //insert into database (assuming that your image field is of blob type, it will accept inputStream type in JDBC API)


         //and finally of course redirect to your upload result page
    }
}
```

The above snippet is just to get you some idea on how to do file upload in servlet. It doesn't involve any file type validation or exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do that using the MVC pattern..I have used mysql databse in this example you can use DBMS of your preference. This code should solve your problem.
**HTML CODE**

add-- enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form tag in html or jsp page

**model class code - encapsulate all fields**

```
private int studentRoll;
private String studentName;
private String studentClass;
private String studentAddress;
private Object studentImage;
private byte image_data[];
```

**servlet code**

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
         if (request.getParameter("submit") != null) {

            String student_Name = request.getParameter("student_name");
            String student_Class = request.getParameter("student_class");
            String student_Address = request.getParameter("student_address");

            Part student_Image = request.getPart("student_image");

            StudentModel student = new StudentModel();
            student.setStudentName(student_Name);
            student.setStudentClass(student_Class);
            student.setStudentAddress(student_Address);
            student.setStudentImage(student_Image);

            StudentDAO stu_dao = new StudentDAO();
            stu_dao.insertStudent(student);
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();;
    }
}
```

**Connection class - DatabaseConnection.java**

```
public static Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/newstudentdatabase", "root", "");
        return connect;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

**dao class - insert method**

```
public void insertStudent(StudentModel student) {
    try (Connection connect = DatabaseConnection.getConnection()) {
        String query = "insert into studentrecord(student_name, student_class, student_address, student_image) values(?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement message = connect.prepareStatement(query);
        message.setString(1, student.getStudentName());
        message.setString(2, student.getStudentClass());
        message.setString(3, student.getStudentAddress());
        message.setBlob(4, ((Part) student.getStudentImage()).getInputStream());
        message.execute();
        connect.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```